# Addition of 2 integers recursively with carry

Tags: c

I'm doing an assignment which requires me to add 2 int and requires me to do recursion. Below is my code but my output is always 10 more then the answer. Why? My initial carry is 0.

```
int add(int n1,int n2,int carry){

    if(n1>0){

        if(carry == 1)
            n1= n1+1;

        if((n1%10+n2%10)>9)
            return n1%10 + n2%10 + 10*add(n1/10,n2/10,1);
        else    
            return n1%10 + n2%10 + 10*add(n1/10,n2/10,0);

    }

    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried adding 999 and 999 the result gave me 2008... every time there is a carry involved there seem to be an addition 10 appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is evident if you follow *by hand* your program. Let's follow add(8, 7, 0):

- carry is 0: nothing to do
- n1%10+n2%10 = 15 > 9: ok we will have a carry
  return 8 + 7 + 10 * add(0, 0, 1) !

The error is here: you get 25 instead of 15 because you correctly add the carry but fail to use only the mod of the sum: it should be ((8 + 7) % 10) + 10 * add(0, 0, 1)

So your code should become:

```
...
if((n1%10+n2%10)>9) {
    return ((n1%10 + n2%10) % 10) + 10*add(n1/10,n2/10,1);
}
else {   
    ...
```

But this code only makes sense for academic purposes. It would be terrible in real world code because you simulate 10 based operation on a 32bits (or more) processor...

Comment: @Jason. If it works, you should accept the answer to notify it for future readers. This is the way SO works :-)

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helps you.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int add(int n1,int n2)
{
        if(n2==0)
                return;

        int carry = n1&n2;
        n1 = n1^n2;
        n2 = carry<<1;
        add(n1,n2);
}
int main()
{
        printf("%d\n",add(29,16));
        return 0;
}
```